# Use commands under directory only for interactive use?

Tags: shell-script, alias

I have a `bin/` under `$HOME`. This contains some augmented versions of common commands. Hence, I don't want these commands to be used by scripts, but only to be used in interactive use.

Is the best I can do to add

```
for f in ~/bin/*
do
    alias "$(basename $f)"="$f"
done
```

to my `~/.bash_profile`? Or is there another solution?

Comment: `PATH` gets inherited from the interactive shell, so aliases or functions seem like the best option. Though you may want to put aliases in `.bashrc` to get them loaded in all interactive shells, not just login shells.

Answer (score 1):

You also can add the lines as follows to your `.bashrc`, which only sets the `PATH` if you are in a interactive shell.

```
if [ "$PS1" ]
then
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
fi
```

Comment: `PATH` will already be exported, so there isn't really any need to export it again.

Comment: This will also set the path for all programs started by that shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use environment modules to manually enable (load) a module setting the desired path

```
module load homebin
```

Where homebin module would look like

```
#%Module1.0
prepend-path PATH ~/bin
```

http://modules.sourceforge.net

Answer (score -2):

It depends on which shell and (unfortunately) which system you are using. Bash, for example, uses different startup files depending on whether it is used as an interactive or non-interactive shell, as explained in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

In principle you should be able to add `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.bashrc` file, which then will be executed only for interactive non-login shells. In practice some systems are configured such that they read `~/.bashrc` also for non-interactive shells.

Related questions:

- [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
- [About .bash_profile, .bashrc, and where should alias be written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902946/about-bash-profile-bashrc-and-where-should-alias-be-written-in)

Comment: That wouldn't help, since the setting would also affect all programs started by the interactive instance of bash.

Comment: @Gilles You are right of course; my bad. I assume this would work if one would mark PATH as no longer to be exported, but that would have terrible side effects. Setting up aliases sounds like a good solution then. Perhaps one could do that in the interactive-only startup file .bashrc?